# Store response HTTP status code after exception in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm developing a REST web service in Ruby on Rails.

After each request I would like to store in the database the response HTTP status code even in presence of some exception. How can I do that?

I have done these two attempts without success:

- after_filter in application controller

  ```
  class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :set_current_rest_request
      after_filter :finalize_current_rest_request
      private
      def set_current_rest_request
          @current_rest_request = RestRequest.new
          @current_rest_request.request_at = DateTime.now
          @current_rest_request.save
      end
      def finalize_current_rest_request
          @current_rest_request.answer_at = DateTime.now
          @current_rest_request.http_status_code = response.status
          @current_rest_request.save
      end
  end
  ```

  Doesn't work because finalize_current_rest_request is not called in case of exceptions
- rescue_from in application controller

  ```
  class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
      before_action :set_current_rest_request
      after_filter :finalize_current_rest_request
      rescue_from Exception, :with => :handle_exception
      private
      def set_current_rest_request
          @current_rest_request = RestRequest.new
          @current_rest_request.request_at = DateTime.now
          @current_rest_request.save
      end
      def finalize_current_rest_request
          @current_rest_request.answer_at = DateTime.now
          @current_rest_request.http_status_code = response.status
          @current_rest_request.save
      end
      def handle_exception(exception)
          finalize_current_rest_request
          raise exception
      end
  end
  ```

  Doesn't work because response.status is still 200 when I call finalize_current_rest_request inside handle_exception, before the raise of the exception

Comment: Can you post some actual code?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @DavidAngulo I added an answer with the solution I adopted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved adding a middleware ([here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) some datails on how rails middlewares work).
In detail, in config/application.rb, I added:

```
config.middleware.insert_before "Rails::Rack::Logger","StoreStatus"
```

the api controller was

```
class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_current_rest_request
    private
    def set_current_rest_request
      @current_rest_request = RestRequest.new
      request.env[:current_rest_request] = @current_rest_request
    end
end
```

and I added the file lib/store_status.rb with the following code:

```
class StoreStatus
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    data = @app.call(env)
    if (env[:current_rest_request])
      rest_request = env[:current_rest_request]
      rest_request.http_status_code = data[0]
      rest_request.save
    end
    data
  end
end
```

Please notice that there may be some syntax error because this code has been obtained refactoring a code which contains other useless complexity for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each action of the controller with a begin rescue block.  Something like:

```
begin
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { redirect_to foos_path, notice: 'Foo was successfully destroyed.' }
rescue 
  @current_rest_request.http_status_code = response.status
  end
end
```

Normally behavior like this is left up to the logs but I am assuming you have a really good reason for doing this.

If you really want it to be dry as you mentioned you can put in your application controller:

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :store_request

def store_request
  current_rest_request = RestRequest.new
  current_rest_request.request_at = DateTime.now
  current_rest_request.http_status_code = response.status
  current_rest_request.save
end
```

Note:  It is often considered bad practice to blanket rescue in the application controller.  I think the best way to actually handle this is to implement a comprehensive logging scheme.

Comment: Maybe I didn't truly get your answer but I think your solution is similar to my rescue_from solution, with the drawback that it is not DRY because I have to repeat the same code in all controllers. I think the solution to my problem is related to Rails middlewares, I have to do more searches on that.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your concerns about dryness.  That said I think investigating a logging implementation is the best approach.

Comment: I will try your solution, but I think this will store always http_status_code 200